# To remove neural-network units or to increase drop-out?

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, dropout

When adding dropout to a neural network, we are randomly removing a fraction of the connections (setting those weights to zero for that specific weight update iteration). If the dropout probability is p, then we are effectively training with a neural network of size 1−p*(Number of original units).

Using this logic, there is not limit how big I can make a network, as long as I proportionately increase dropout, I can always effectively train with the same sized network, and thereby just increasing the number of "independent" models working together, making a larger ensemble model. Thereby **improving generalization** of the model.

For example, if a network with 2 units already achieves good results in the training set (but not in unseen data -i.e validation or test sets-), also a network with 4 units + dropout 0.5 (ensemble of 2 models), and also a network with 8 units + dropout 0.75 (ensemble of 4 models)... and also a network with 1000 units with a dropout of 0.998 (ensemble of 500 models)!

In practice it is recommended to keep dropout at 0.5, which advises against the approach mentioned above. So there seem to be reasons for this.

What speaks against blowing up a model together with an adjusted dropout parameter?

Comment: neural networks are computationally bound... the more units you use the more time it takes to perform one iteration.  but you have to run 1000s of iterations, then try different hyper paramers.. rinse and repeat.

Comment: I don't think the ensemble 'metaphor' is the right way of thinking about this.  I think its better to think of the relus as 'knot points' of a piecewise linear spline (clearer in 1d). dropout forces redunancy, reducing the effective number of knotponts. I think you would rather start with little dropout (to explore space), then gradually add dropout.

Comment: @seanv507 The 'ensemble' metaphor being wrong could definetly answer my question, but I don't quite understand your intuitive way of thinking dropout. Could you maybe elaborate the 'knot points' analogy in an answer?